# How to present an alert when a sheet is showing

Tags: swiftui, alert

In the following code what I'm trying to do is detect when the app becomes newly active, and show an alert if it is. And this works fine, when the main view is being shown. But if the sheet is being shown (ie, show the sheet, put the app in the background, bring it up again), then the alert won't show, and you get the error down below.

And note that from that point on, you can't even bring up the alert via the button "show alert"; it does nothing.

The real code is vastly more complicated than this, but the gist of things is that: I want to show the alert when a condition has been met (in this case the app becomes active), but nothing else is going on (no sheets or whatever are being presented). It's like I need to check something:

```
if itsOkToShowAlert {
   showAlert = true
}
```

Any ideas?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!").padding()
            Button("Show sheet") {
                showingSheet = true
            }.padding()
            Button("Show alert") {
                showAlert = true
            }.padding()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("HELLO SHEET!").font(.largeTitle)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .task(id: scenePhase) {
            if scenePhase == .active {
                print("Activated")
                showAlert = true
            }
        }
        .alert("HAVE AN ALERT", isPresented: $showAlert) {
            let _ = print("Showing alert")
            Button("OK", role: .cancel) {
                print("alert button pressed")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

This is the error that pops up when trying to show the alert when the sheet is showing (which makes sense...in a way).

```
2023-05-27 17:18:50.217767-0700 testalert[44589:31594186] [Presentation] Attempt to present <SwiftUI.PlatformAlertController: 0x16282f000> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x162819400> (from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x162819400>) which is already presenting
```

EDIT: Ok, I understand that I can't show the alert if "something" is being presented, but is there a way to detect if nothing is being presented, and then show the alert?

Comment: You can't present a view controller (including an alert controller) on a view controller that is already presenting a  view controller; there can be only one. I suppose SwiftUI makes it harder to see that.

Comment: If sheet is presented, then the alert must be called from in sheet.